How to get selected option as default?
I am trying to have the selectedOption as default, but it's not working. I also tried to do:
const selectedOption = 'Select an option'

but that does not work either. I can see the <option> tag, but it's empty. What am I doing wrong?
<template>
    <select v-model="selectedOption" class="">
        <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.value">
          {{ option.text }}
        </option>
      </select>
</template>

const options = ref([
    {
      selectedOption: 'Select an option',
    },
    {
      value: 'option1',
      text: 'Option 1',
    },
    {
      value: 'option2',
      text: 'Option 2',
    },
  ])


I think you are doing it all wrong.
First, create a variable to handle the option that is being selected,
Then you can initialize it with the first item in options array

Does this answer your question? Set default value to option select menu

In your script section, modify your options array to below.
Also create a variable selectedOption and default it to empty string which meets the first index value of the options array
const selectedOption = ref('');

const options = ref([
{
value: '', text:'Select an option',
},
{
value: 'option1', text: 'Option 1'
},
{
value: 'option2', text: 'Option 2'
}

])


This looks like it's working well
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const selected = ref('B')

const options = ref([
  { text: 'One', value: 'A' },
  { text: 'Two', value: 'B' },
  { text: 'Three', value: 'C' }
])
</script>

<template>
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.value">
      {{ option.text }}
    </option>
  </select>

  <div>Selected: {{ selected }}</div>
</template>

Here is a playground.
Here's the docs related to this.
